# Pointers in C Language (Code Explanation)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Could someone please explain to me step by step what this code does?

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int numbers [2] [3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int (*num_ptr) [3]= numbers;

    printf ("value is : %d\n",*(*(num_ptr+1)));
     printf ("value is : %d\n",**num_ptr);
     printf ("value is : %d\n",*(*num_ptr)+1);
     printf ("value is : %d\n",*(*(num_ptr+1))+1);

    //return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `numbers` is an array of two elements, each of which is an array of three integers. `num_ptr` is a pointer to an array of three integers that is set to the beginning of `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to understand the code if you use array index notation. `A[B]` is the same as `*(A+B)`, and vice versa, in all cases;  with a special case being that `A[0]` is the same as `*(A + 0)`, which is the same as `*A` if `A` is a valid pointer.

Applying this transformation, your code becomes:

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n", num_ptr[1][0]);
 printf ("value is : %d\n", num_ptr[0][0]);
 printf ("value is : %d\n", num_ptr[0][1]);
 printf ("value is : %d\n", num_ptr[1][0] + 1);
```

Hopefully you can take it from here.

The definition of `num_ptr` ensures that `num_ptr[A][B]` is the same as `numbers[A][B]`. Your program would be unchanged if the printf statements used `numbers` instead of `num_ptr`, because the array `numbers` decays to the same pointer value that `num_ptr` has.

Comment: Isn't the third one `num_ptr[0][0] + 1` ?

Comment: @alain no, the original was `*(*(num_ptr+1))+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
*(*(num_ptr+1))
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    skip the first row
```

*No columns skipped after that*

Ans = 4

---

```
**num_ptr
```

*No rows or columns skipped*

Ans = 1

---

```
*(*num_ptr)+1
^^^^^^^^^^^
no rows or column skipped
```

*add 1 to the ans*

Ans = 2

---

```
*(*(num_ptr+1))+1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
skip first row, no columns skipped
```

*add 1 to answer*

Ans = 5

Answer (score 0):

1. `int (*num_ptr) [3]= numbers;` declares `num_ptr` as a pointer to an array of 3 `int` and initializes it to the first element of array `numbers`. It is equivalent to

   ```
   int (*num_ptr) [3]= &numbers[0];
   ```
2. `num_ptr` points to array `numbers[0]` and `num_ptr+1` points to `numbers[1]`. `*(num_ptr+1)` dereferences `num_ptr+1` and gives an array. As array decays to pointer to its first element in most context, `*(num_ptr+1)` will finally give `&number[1][0]`. So, `*(*(num_ptr+1))` is equivalent to `*(*(&number[1])) == *(&number[1][0]) == 4`.
3. Similarly, `**num_ptr` will give `1`, `*(*num_ptr)+1)` will give `1+1 =2` and `*(*(num_ptr+1))+1` will give `4+1 =5`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's remove redundant parenthese inside the `printf` statement.

It will look like

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **(num_ptr + 1)  );
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **num_ptr );
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **num_ptr + 1 );
 printf ("value is : %d\n",**( num_ptr + 1 ) + 1 );
```

`num_ptr` is declared like pointer to the first element of array `numbers`.
The elements of the array `numbers` are two on-dimensional arrays `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 4, 5, 6 }`

So expression `*num_ptr` yields the first one-dimensional array. In expressions with rare exceptions arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. Thus this expression `*num_ptr` is converted to pointer to first element that is to `1` And `**num_ptr` gives the value.

As result this statement

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **num_ptr );
```

outputs 1.

This statement

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **num_ptr + 1 );
```

just adds 1 to the value of the prvious expression and outputs it that is 2.

As `num_ptr` is pointer to the first one-dimensioanle array then `num_ptr + 1` is pointer to the second on-dimensional array `{ 4, 5, 6 }`. Other calculations are the same as described above.

Thus statement

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n", **(num_ptr + 1)  );
```

outputs 4 and statement

```
 printf ("value is : %d\n",**( num_ptr + 1 ) + 1 );
```

outputs 4 + 1 that is 5.